# What happens if I dont Unwind a Segue in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I've an app where there are more than 10 `ViewControllers` and there is a `MenuViewController` Which is triggered by all the `ViewControllers`. And `MenuViewController` Triggers all `ViewControllers`. So in app I will not unwind a Segue but keep on triggering the segues.

Scheme:

[image: Scheme]

Does it give any side effect like out of memory or app hanging kind of? 
Will it be fine if I keep on triggering segues without unwinding them?

Somebody Please Help ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll eventually run out of memory if you keep pushing new view controllers on the navigation stack without removing the previous ones. If you never want to pop back to a previous view controller, you can remove the complete navigation history after the push transition has finished in each view controllers viewDidAppear::

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[self];
}
```

Alternatively, you can put this logic in a central place by setting your navigation controller's delegate and implementing navigationController:didShowViewController:animated::

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[navigationController.viewControllers.lastObject];
}
```